# Can I have my Destiny character on two of the same systems?

Tags: destiny

I was wondering if I could have my Destiny character on two of the same system because I started playing on my brothers ps4 because I was getting my own next month.
when I get my own ps4 can I port my destiny character on my brothers ps4 to my own ps4?

Comment: @DavidYell do PS3 to PS4 transfers work the same as PS4 to PS4?

Comment: @ben Destiny savegames are linked to your PSN account. It doesn't matter what platform you play it on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **provided you log in with the same PSN account.**

If you have been using your brothers PSN account on his PS4, then you will need to log in with his PSN account in order to continue using your character - I'm unsure of the effects of that (whether he will be able to continue playing or not). If you have been using your *own* PSN account on his PS4, then you'll just use that.

Comment: All character saves are to the Destiny servers, so they will work on any system in the same family using the same login (PSN or Xbox Live). This is not a transfer, it's a live interaction so you can go back and forth between multiple systems as much as you like. The one catch is that you can only use a specific login on one system at a time, so if your character is on someone else's account you'll have to work out shared time.